# How to disable Ctrl+Alt+S on Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: shortcut-keys, 23.04

I test most tricks to disable toggle window size on ubuntu 23.04 but all of them works on previous versions like 22.04 and 18.04 and none of them works on 23.04. Has anyone ever found a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to play with extensions. I had the same issue on 23.04. The problem was in "Screenshot Window Sizer" extension

Comment: Excellent  It work's for me 

Answer (score 1):

The easier way to disable the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> shortcut is just running this command in a terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings toggle-shaded "['disabled']"
```

Another way to disable the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> shortcut is to use the `dconf-editor` tool, which allows you to modify various settings on your system. You can install `dconf-editor` from the Software Center or by using the command:

```
sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

Then, you can launch dconf Editor and navigate to `/org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/toggle-shaded`. You will see a list of values that represent the keyboard combinations for this action. You can click on the value and change it to `[‘disabled’]`.

Comment: unfortunately it seems like doesn't work
`➜  ~ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings toggle-shaded 
['disabled']
`

Comment: Can you tell me more details

Comment: `gsettings list-recursively` has no result for `ctrl+alt+s` composition. and also there is no entry in keyboard shortcuts list. is there any option to intercept which program consume this shortcut?

Comment: Can you edit your question to make it more clear? Describe precisely what problem you have, and what you want to achieve. What is Ctrl+Alt+s causing on your system? As you stated in the comment, by default, that keyboard combination is not even assigned.